# Можно ли в TypeScript, задать нефиксированое количество полей определенного типа в объекте?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Например, я хочу, чтобы в объекте лежало неограниченное количество полей, но чтоб все они были строками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, это делается очень просто:

```
interface Foo {
  [key:string]: string // all key must be string
}
```

Вот тут можно прочитать побольше: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/index-signatures.html